# Matlab error handling convert to C

Tags: matlab, architecture, enums, matlab-coder

I thought of using object oriented design for a Matlab code and later to convert it to C, where at the end it should be used for a DSP - Processor.

What I am not sure about, is how to do the error handling. In C it should be with enum as far as I know and if I use exception in my matlab code, I am not sure how matlab will convert it to C.

Another possibility is to implement enum class and to use it instead of exceptions.

Since I have not so much experience in software architecture, any suggestion is more then welcome.

Comment: Retagging with MATLAB Coder, which is used for C code generation, not MATLAB Compiler or deployment products.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly old question, but I think it's a pretty important question as it gets to some foundational issues regarding how best to use MATLAB Coder and architect your code.

A good error handling system is very important to any moderately sized codebase, so it's important to get it structured.  In code targeted for MATLAB Coder, you cannot use any of the normal exception functions (try, catch, error, etc.), and even 'assert' takes on special meaning in Coder.  That means you're on your own to create a good error handling system.  This is unfortunate, but not insurmountable.

You could just make an enumerated type with different error codes and return the appropriate enum.  This is a very standard C way of doing things, and it would clearly translate from MATLAB to C very cleanly.  It has a few downsides:

1. You must maintain the enum class for the addition of every error condition.
2. It does not directly facilitate a stack trace.
3. It's likely that the same error will be reused in different places, which doesn't allow for definitive tracing of the error location.
4. It does not provide human-readable error statements.
5. It doesn't allow for runtime data to be returned, for instance variable values that were in use in the bottom-level function that may have caused the error.

These are all things that the inbuilt MATLAB system does provide, so it'd be nice to have some of those things.

In my codebase, I've developed an error system that has served me well.  It uses some powerful tools in Coder to make a clean, easy to use error system that looks a bit like MATLAB's own error system.  It also provides nice connection to error handling in the program that ends up calling the library produced by Coder.

The first function is the errorcontainer.  This is a function that houses the persistent variables that store the runtime errors.

```
function [ idnum, errorid, errorstring, inneridnum ] = errorcontainer(functionname, varargin ) %#codegen
%ERRORCONTAINER The container function for error processing
%   This function contains the error ID table, and can assign new error
%   codes or look up error codes.  
%  
%   Examples:
%     To register a new error and retrieve a unique error ID:
%       idnum = errorcontainter( 'register', ID, MESSAGE )
%       where ID and MESSAGE are strings.  ID is a short machine readable
%       string, and MESSAGE is human-readable.
%
%   Optionally, an INNERIDNUM can be provided to indicate an error code for
%   a inner (lower-level) error related to this.  This will allow
%   chaining of error messages:
%
%       idnum = errorcontainter( 'register', ID, MESSAGE, inneridnum )
%
%   ID and MESSAGE can have maximum lengths of 2048 characters.  Anything
%   longer will be truncated.
%
%     e.g.  idnum = errorcontainer('register', ...
%                                  'FOO_INVALIDTYPE', ...
%                                  'First input must be an int.');
%           idnum will be a negative int32 returned.
%
%        If the ID matches an existing ID, the message will be overwritten
%        and the same idnum will be returned (the database does not grow).
%
%     To lookup an existing error code:
%        [idnum, errorid, errorstring] = errorcontainer('lookup', idnum);
%
%   See also:  errorcode2string, registererror


persistent IDLIST;
persistent ERRORSTRINGLIST;
persistent INNERID;

width = 2048;

if isempty(IDLIST)
    IDLIST = char(zeros(1,width));
    tempstr = 'ERRORCONTAINER_UNKNOWNERRORID';
    IDLIST(1,1:numel(tempstr)) = tempstr;
end
if isempty(ERRORSTRINGLIST)
    ERRORSTRINGLIST = char(zeros(1,width));
    tempstr = 'Unknown Error';
    ERRORSTRINGLIST(1,1:numel(tempstr)) = tempstr;
end
if isempty(INNERID)
    INNERID = zeros(1,1,'int32');
end

coder.varsize('IDLIST', 'ERRORSTRINGLIST', 'INNERID', [], [1,1]);
coder.varsize('errorstring', 'errorid');

switch lower(functionname)
    case 'register'
        % First see if the listed ID matches any in the database.

        errorid = varargin{1};
        if numel(errorid) > width
            errorid = errorid(1:width);
        end

        if (nargin == 4)
            inneridnum = int32(varargin{3});
        else
            inneridnum = int32(0);
        end

        errorstring = varargin{2};
        if numel(errorstring) > width
            errorstring = errorstring(1:width);
        end

        matchindex = 0;
        for i = 1:size(IDLIST,1)
            if ( strcmpi(errorid, deblank(IDLIST(i,:))) && (inneridnum == INNERID(i) ) )
                matchindex = i;
            end
        end


        if (matchindex > 0)
            idnum = int32(-matchindex);
        else
            idnum = int32(-(size(IDLIST,1)+1));
            tempstr = char(zeros(1,width));
            tempstr(1:numel(errorid)) = errorid;
            IDLIST = [IDLIST ; tempstr];  % In Coder, cannot grow with indexing.  Have to concatinte and reassign.

            tempstr = char(zeros(1,width));
            tempstr(1:numel(errorstring)) = errorstring;
            ERRORSTRINGLIST = [ERRORSTRINGLIST ; tempstr];

            INNERID = [INNERID; inneridnum];

        end

    case 'lookup'
        idnum = varargin{1};
        tidnum = idnum;
        if ((-tidnum > size(IDLIST,1)) || (-tidnum <= 0 ))
            tidnum = int32(-1);
        end
        errorid = deblank(IDLIST(-tidnum,:));
        errorstring = deblank(ERRORSTRINGLIST(-tidnum,:));
        inneridnum = INNERID(-tidnum);

    otherwise
        idnum = int32(-1);
        errorid = deblank(IDLIST(-idnum,:));
        errorstring = deblank(ERRORSTRINGLIST(-idnum,:));
        inneridnum = int32(0);
end
end
```

The heart of this function is a large switch statement that allows selection of the task to be performed.  The errorcontainer function is intended as an internal storage and service routine for the error handling system.

The main function used to "throw" errors is the `registererror` function, shown here:

```
function idnum = registererror(messageid, errorstring, varargin) %#codegen
%REGISTERERROR Registers a message id and error string with error system
%  Given a message ID string and an error code string (human-readable),
%  will register the strings with the error subsystem and generate a
%  negative ID number to return.
%
%  Example:
%    idnum = registererror('FOO_INVALIDINPUT', 'Invalid input to function foo');
%  
%  Optionally, an inner id number can be handed to the registration to
%  assocaite this error with a lower-level error previously registered.
%    idnuminner = registererror('BAR_INTERNALERROR', 'Internal error in bar');
%    idnum = registererror('FOO_INVALIDINPUT', 'Invalid input to function foo', idnuminner);
%
%  See Also: errorcode2string, errorcontainer

coder.inline('never')
switch nargin
    case 2
        idnum  = errorcontainer('register', messageid, errorstring);
    case 3
        idnum  = errorcontainer('register', messageid, errorstring, varargin{1});
end
end
```

The `registererror` function takes a error tag string (usually the function name where the error occurred, followed by a colon, followed by some identifier of what happened) and a human-readable error message.  It registers the error in the global storage and returns an error identifier as an int32.  The rule for my code is that a value of int32(0) means there was no error, and a negative value is one of these registered error identifiers.

The values returned by registererror are not unique per-error-condition. They are reference handles into the error container, and can be used to retrieve the error tag string and human-readable strings.

In my code, the use of registererror usually goes something like this:

```
...
output = someFunctionThatShouldReturnZeroIfSuccessful(filename);
if (output ~= 0)
    result = registerror('MYFUNC:THESOMEFUNCTIONFAILED', ['The function that should return zero returned something else for filename: ', filename]);
    return;
end
...
```

Within the human-readable string, I can append string data from the actual execution.  In this example, I appended the filename that failed in my theoretical function.  I make the return values of all my functions int32, and all of them can come from a call to registererror.

There's an additional optional call to registererror.  One thing that is handy to do is to create a stack of errors.  Sometimes an error in a deeper function caused the problem, and we'd like a full stack trace.  This is easy to do, as inner error ids can be optionally handed to registererror.  Let's see an example of that:

```
...
result = someFunctionThatShouldReturnZeroIfSuccessful(filename);
if (result ~= 0)
    result = registerror('MYFUNC:THESOMEFUNCTIONFAILED', ['The function that should return zero returned something else for filename: ', filename], result);
    return;
end
...
```

In this case, the someFunction... returned a value that had itself been generated by a call to registererror, and that result value was added as a third argument to the registererror call here, which returns a yet different error value.  What can we do with this value?

Well, we need a third function, which is often callable by code using our library.  This function is called `errorcode2string`, and as the name implies, it can take one of our error codes and return the two strings, as well as any inner error code related to the error.  Here's errorcode2string:

```
function [errorid, errorstring, innercode] = errorcode2string(errorcode) %#codegen
%ERRORCODE2STRING Return strings given an error code
%  Given an error code returned by any of the library functions, will
%  return a string with human-readable information about the error.  The
%  error codes are, in some cases, dynamically generated, so the codes
%  themselves should not be used for programmatic flow control except that
%  a negative value in a return always indicates an error occurred.
%
%  Example:
%    [errorid, errorstring, innercode] = errorcode2string(errorcode);
%
%  - errorcode is an int32 value. 
%
%  - errorid is a string that is machine-readable and can be used to trap
%  specific error codes.
%  
%  - errorstring is the returned 1 by N string of the human-readable error
%  information.
%
%  - innercode is the int32 error code of an inner error message if any.
%  It is a negative value of an error code if present, 0 if this is the
%  innermost error.
%
%  See Also: registererror

[~, errorid, errorstring, innercode] = errorcontainer('lookup', errorcode);

end
```

As you can see, this function is really just a wrapper around the errorcontainer, but it's nice to do this to keep things tidy for anyone calling into the library.

### Example:

So let's run a quick example.  Imagine an inner function failed, and registererror was called like this:

```
result = registererror('SOMEFUNC:SOMETASK', 'Something terrible happened.')
result = -2
```

The calling function notices the result is not 0, but is instead a negative error code, and itself throws an error:

```
result = registererror('CALLINGFUNC:TOPTASK', 'Trying to do some high level thing failed.', result);
result = -3
```

This value of -3 is returned by our library to the calling code, so it knows an error occurred simply because the result was negative.  It can then call errorcode2string to get more information about the error.

```
[errorid, errorstring, innercode] = errorcode2string(int32(-3))
errorid = CALLINGFUNC:TOPTASK
errorstring = Trying to do some high level thing failed.
innercode = -2
```

Since innercode is still negative, if the calling program is so inclined, it can call errorcode2string to find out more information down the functional stack.  Really, this is how you'd find out the root error that happened.

```
[errorid, errorstring, innercode] = errorcode2string(int32(-2))
errorid = SOMEFUNC:SOMETASK
errorstring = Something terrible happened.
innercode = 0
```

Now innercode is 0, so we know we can stop.

This system has worked pretty well for my project, and I hope it's helpful.  It was one of the first things I had to figure out to use Coder, and it taught me a lot about good architecture practices in MATLAB Coder, including how do make a data structure that is globally accessible.